# Energy release/gain in superposition (in Stern-Gerlach)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

Let's have a quantum system in superpositon of two states $|e>$ and |g> with coefficients a and b. Now the system interracts with a field and is projected on either |e> or|g>. The question is what energy does the system release or accept and where gets it from?
An example is the Stern Gerlach experiment. The electron is projected in spin up or down. But what energy it releases going from $a|e>+b|g>->|g>$ and where it takes it from (if from the magnet - what happens with its domains and what it apply for photons being involved as carriers from a pure magnetic field to an electron?

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

In quantum mechanics, you can prepare your state in superpositions of energy, and measurements can collapse your state and change its energy.

In a lab, I can prepare a photon to be in superposition state of $(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Which means that, if I were to measure my state with a detector, half of the time I have a photon, and half of the time I don't.

One "conservation law" that remains the same with clasical mechanics is that the **expected value of the energy will stay the same**. So for example in our photon detection experiment, the expected value of the energy is 1/2 the energy of a photon, and this is what we will measure since half the time we'll measure 0 and half the time we will measure energy of a photon. (This works in the cases that I can think of, although there might be some experiements where some tricks are done to voilate this).

Sometimes this is "measurement collapses energy wavefunction" feature of quantum mechanics is exploited. For instance, in the [quantum zeno effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect) you can show that simply by constantly making measurements frequently, you can force a state to not evolve in time and remain "locked" in a particular state forever!

Comment: you say  "measurements can collapse your state and change its energy". If the energy changes for a single particle (not statistically) it also must obey conservation law IMO and  release/take a photon. Otherwise it looks like in SG exp that the electron does not have energy (due to spin) even if it is in say 99% up and 1% down superposition state -- then energy appears because for an the electron up/down 100%  (you need energy(photon) to make transition from spin down to spin up) and vice versa. And notta bene the magnet doesn't change at all.

Comment: I imagine a exp in which the (single) electron is 99% up and 1% down - and then measurement gives down result. Would there be a photon released by that electron?

Comment: In fact in SG the change of the trajectory of the electron is due to interraction with magnetic field. If the electron does not gain/release photons (energy) so the magnet does not change at all. Then there is an absurd situation - interraction without changes!